# how to get tbody from table from python beautiful soup ?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap Year & Winners ( first & second columns ) from "List of finals matches" table (second table) from 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals: I'm using the code below:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.samhsa.gov/data/NSDUH/2k10State/NSDUHsae2010/NSDUHsaeAppC2010.htm"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr')
for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr'):
    first_column = row.findAll('th')[0].contents
    third_column = row.findAll('td')[2].contents
    print first_column, third_column
```

With the above code, I was able to get first & thrid column just fine. But when I use the same code with `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals`,  It could not find tbody as its element, but I can see the tbody when I inspect the element.

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

print soup.findAll('table')[2]

    soup.findAll('table')[2].tbody.findAll('tr')
    for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr'):
        first_column = row.findAll('th')[0].contents
        third_column = row.findAll('td')[2].contents
        print first_column, third_column
```

Here's what I got from comment error:

```
'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-fedd08c6da16> in <module>()
      7 # print soup.findAll('table')[2]
      8 
----> 9 soup.findAll('table')[2].tbody.findAll('tr')
     10 for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr'):
     11     first_column = row.findAll('th')[0].contents

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

'
```

Answer (score 17):

If you are inspecting through the inspect tool in the browser it will insert the `tbody` tags.

The source code, may, or may not contain them.  I suggest looking at the source view if you really want to know.

Either way, you do not need to traverse to the tbody, simply:

`soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')` should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_finals"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
for tr in soup.findAll('table')[2].findAll('tr'):
    #get data
```

And then search what you need in the table :)

Answer (score 1):

Directly run the below code.

`tr_elements = soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')`

By doing this, you can access the all the `<tr>`; You will have to use for loop for doing this (There are other possible ways to iterate too). Don't try to find the **tbody**, it gets added by default.

**Note:**

If you are having a problem in getting to the desired tag, decompose the previous tags with `.decompose()` method.