# How to scrape data from the AKC Dog Registration site with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the American Kernel Club (https://www.akc.org/reg/dogreg_stats.cfm) and I have been having some trouble. I am referring to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522820/how-to-get-tbody-from-table-from-python-beautiful-soup) and I can get all of the rows on the second table but I cannot format them.

So here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = https://www.akc.org/reg/dogreg_stats.cfm
r. requests.get(r)
data= r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
rows = soup.find_all('table')[1].find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cells = soup.find_all('td')
    firstRanking = cell[1].get_text()
    print(firstRanking)
```

All it prints out is

```
More on Registration   Trends:
More on Registration   Trends:
More on Registration   Trends:
More on Registration   Trends:
More on Registration   Trends:
More on Registration   Trends:
More on Registration   Trends:
```

Instead of the actual rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your variable "***cells***", you want to be finding all '**`td`**' elements of that ROW, **not** of the entire "soup" object.

It should look like this:

```
cells = row.find_all('td')
```

Also, I believe there is an error in the line after this, it be "cells" not "cell" that is referenced:

```
firstRanking = cells[1].get_text()
```

This will make the for loop look like this:

```
for row in rows:
  cells = row.find_all('td')
  firstRanking = cells[1].get_text()
  print(firstRanking)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake I did was on this line  **rows = soup.find_all('table')[1].find_all('tr')** <- this created a list item. 
To fix the problem I change the line to **table= soup.find_all('table')[1]** then **rows=table.find_all('tr')**