# python mechanize check dates/time for an exam from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to check the dates/times availability for an exam using Python mechanize and send someone an email if a particular date/time becomes available in the result (result page screenshot attached)

```
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
URL = "http://secure.dre.ca.gov/PublicASP/CurrentExams.asp"


br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open(URL)


# there are some errors in doctype and hence filtering the page content a bit
response.set_data(response.get_data()[200:])

br.set_response(response)
br.select_form(name="entry_form")

# select Oakland for the 1st set of checkboxes

for i in range(0,     len(br.find_control(type="checkbox",name="cb_examSites").items)):
    if i ==2:
        br.find_control(type="checkbox",name="cb_examSites").items[i].selected =True

# select salesperson for the 2nd set of checkboxes

for i in range(0, len(br.find_control(type="checkbox",name="cb_examTypes").items)):
    if i ==1:
        br.find_control(type="checkbox",name="cb_examTypes").items[i].selected =True

reponse = br.submit()
print  reponse.read()
```

I am able to get the response but for some reason the data within my table is missing

here are the buttons from the initial html page

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Exam List" name="B1">
<input type="button" value="Clear" name="B2" onclick="clear_entries()">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="GO">
```

one part of the output (submit response) where the actual data is lying

```
<table summary="California Exams Scheduling" class="General_list" width="100%" cellspacing="0"> <EVERTHING INBETWEEN IS MISSING HERE>
</table>
```

All the data within the table is missing. I have provided a screenshot of the table element from chrome browser.

1. Can someone please tell me what could be wrong ?
2. Can someone please tell me how to get the date/time out of the response (assuming I have to use BeautifulSoup) and so has to be something on these lines. I am trying to find out if a particular date I have in mind (say March 8th) in the response shows up a Begin Time of 1:30 pm..screenshot attached

   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
   print soup.find(name="table")

---

update - looks like my issue might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522820/how-to-get-tbody-from-table-from-python-beautiful-soup) and am trying my options . I tried the below as per one of the answers but cannot see any tr elements in the data (though can see this in the page source when I check it manually)

```
soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
```

[image]

---

Update - Modfied this to use selenium, will try and do further at some point soon

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3


myURL = "http://secure.dre.ca.gov/PublicASP/CurrentExams.asp"
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get(myURL) # Load page

element = browser.find_element_by_id("Checkbox5")
element.click()


element = browser.find_element_by_id("Checkbox13")
element.click()

element = browser.find_element_by_name("B1")
element.click()
```

Comment: The website is probably using JavaScript to render the page which BeautifulSoup doesn't know how to run , you'll need to use something like Selenium to load the page in an actual browser

Comment: thx max, I will try that out !

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, maybe this can help someone. I took your problem as a training exercise. I completed it using the Requests package. (I use python 3.9)

The code below is in two parts:

- the request to retrieve the data injected into the table after the POST request.

  ```
  ## the request part

  url = "https://secure.dre.ca.gov/PublicASP/CurrentExams.asp"
  headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"}

  params = {
  "cb_examSites": [
      "'Fresno'",
      "'Los+Angeles'",
      "'SF/Oakland'",
      "'Sacramento'",
      "'San+Diego'"
  ],
  "cb_examTypes": [
      "'Broker'",
      "'Salesperson'"
  ],
  "B1": "Get+Exam+List",
  "action": "GO"
  }

  s = rq.Session()
  r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
  s.headers.update({"Cookie": "%s=%s" % (r.cookies.keys()[0], r.cookies.values()[0])})
  r2 = s.post(url=url, data=params)
  soup = bs(r2.content, "lxml") # contain data you want
  ```
- Parsing the response (a lot of ways to do it mine is maybe a bit stuffy)

  ```
  table = soup.find_all("table", class_="General_list")[0]

  titles = [el.text for el in table.find_all("strong")]

  def beetweenBr(soupx):
      final_str = []
      for br in soupx.findAll('br'):
      next_s = br.nextSibling
      if not (next_s and isinstance(next_s,NavigableString)):
          continue
      next2_s = next_s.nextSibling
      if next2_s and isinstance(next2_s,Tag) and next2_s.name == 'br':
          text = str(next_s).strip()
          if text:
              final_str.append(next_s.strip())
   return "\n".join(final_str)

   d = {}
   trs = table.find_all("tr")
   for tr in trs:
        tr_text = tr.text
        if tr_text in titles:
             curr_title = tr_text
             splitx = curr_title.split(" - ")
             area, job = splitx[0].split(" ")[0], splitx[1].split(" ")[0]
        if not job in d.keys():
             d[job] = {}
        if not area in d[job].keys():
             d[job][area] = []
        continue
        if (not tr_text in titles) & (tr_text != "DateBegin TimeLocationScheduledCapacity"):
             tds = tr.find_all("td")
             sub = []
             for itd, td in enumerate(tds):
                 if itd == 2:
                     sub.append(beetweenBr(td))
                 else :
                     sub.append(td.text)
            d[job][area].append(sub)
  ```

"d" contain data u want. I didn't go as far as sending an email yet.

Comment: Thank you for trying it out and adding the answer here @ce.teuf